# How to make a single tab unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I use the following Code to create single tabs, but I also want one tab to be a link, not a tab.

```
<navi>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="/" title="linkxtab 1">link 1</a></li>
        <li c-tab="tab-2" title="tab 2">link 2</li>
        <li c-tab="tab-3" title="tab 3">link 3</li>
        <li c-tab="tab-4" title="tab 4">link 4</li>
    </ul>
</navi>
```

Whenever I click on 'link 1', the other tabs disappear because the codes apparently think I want to activate this tab that actually should be a link and therefore has no content. This happens when I click on the *li*, not the *a*, because my 'tabsmenu' styling has some padding between the *li* and *a* in it.

Now my question is the following: Is there a CSS-code to enable only this one *li* without disabling its *a*? I already tried `pointer-event:none;` out, but this - of course - results in blocking everything in the *li*, also the *a*.

I use this script for the tabs:

```
$('.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab = $(this).attr('c-tab');
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('selected');
    $('.tabscontent').removeClass('selected');

    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("#"+tab).addClass('selected');
     return false;
});
```

Is there a way to somehow block only one this one tab with a piece of code by renaming it with something?

Thank You!

//NOTE: I still want the tabs to work, and only the tab called 'linkxtab 1' should not work, except for its link.

Comment: Have to tried `href="javascript:void(0)"` for the anchor tag?

Comment: try e.preventDefault(); on anchor click to avoid page redirection if thats what you are looking for

Comment: Or if you want the full tab to be a clickable link, set the width and height of the <a> to 100%;

Comment: I want the link to work and the tab shouldn't at the same time!

Comment: a can have different states like  (a:active) -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp -- you might be able to just use those to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.tabs > li {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs > li > a{
    pointer-events: all!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very good idea! Although, I still want the tabs to work and this only makes the link work. (I'm going to edit this info into my question!)

Comment: Alright! I changed `<li><a href="/" title="linkxtab 1">link 1</a></li>` to `<li class="x"><a href="/" title="linkxtab 1">link 1</a></li>` and added `.x { pointer-events: none;}` + `.x a { pointer-events: all!important; }`, it works! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If there is any `a` in clicked `li` then redirect to the `href` of the link.

```
$('.tabs li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('a').length) {
        window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }

    var tab = $(this).attr('c-tab');
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('selected');
    $('.tabscontent').removeClass('selected');

    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("#" + tab).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this would break, as soon as you include links in your other tabs. I would suggest that you dont add the event handler to the first tab in the first place

Comment: This is basically an idea. I think OP will use it as he want. @sayCrispy

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following to check if the element click was anchor or not and then proceed with rest of the operation.

```
$('li').on('click',function(e)
{
    var target = $(e.target);
      if(!target.is("a"))
      return false;       
});
```